# pointer to member variable in nested struct

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

For the below class, how do I represent the pointer to the member variable `qux` of one of the instances of `Bar`?

```
struct Foo {
  struct Bar {
    int qux;
  } bar1, bar2;
};
```

This is needed when I use the `boost::multi_index` container and need to use `qux` as the key, which is needed in the key extractor

```
template<class Class,typename Type,Type Class::*PtrToMember>
struct boost::multi_index::member
```

Comment: why ask this again? I just saw the exact same question less than an hour ago.

Comment: @Bot why assume it was asked again when clearly it was just edited by a a community member? **[image](http://i.imgur.com/dGv8orA.png
)** _(Just stay on the "newest question" tab if you don't want to see "activity ranked" questions._)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming the intention is to create a boost multi_index container of `Foo`s and use `qux` as the key. Though `qux` isn't a member of `Foo`, you can achieve this by indexing on the member `Foo::bar1` and providing a custom comparison predicate for the ordered index. For example, if you are trying to create an `ordered_unique` key, you would write it like this:

```
ordered_unique<member<Foo, Foo::Bar, &Foo::bar1>, compare_foo_bar>
```

where `compare_foo_bar` is a friend of `Foo::Bar` and is defined as need:

```
struct compare_foo_bar
{
bool operator()(const Foo::Bar& lhs, const Foo::Bar& rhs)
{
  return lhs.qux < rhs.qux;
}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case you have `Class = Foo::Bar`, `Type = int` and `PtrToMember = &Foo::Bar::qux`, so this should work

```
boost::multi_index::member<Foo::Bar, int, &Foo::Bar::qux>
```

---

Based on your comment below, I modified the [basic example](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/example/basic.cpp) from the Boost.MultiIndex tutorial to match your use case. The original example contains the following `struct`

```
/* an employee record holds its ID, name and age */
struct employee
{
  int         id;
  std::string name;
  int         age;

  employee(int id_,std::string name_,int age_):id(id_),name(name_),age(age_){}
  // ...
};
```

And the `multi_index` container is defined as

```
typedef multi_index_container<
  employee,
  indexed_by<
    ordered_unique<
      tag<id>,  BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(employee,int,id)>,
    ordered_non_unique<
      tag<name>,BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(employee,std::string,name)>,
    ordered_non_unique<
      tag<age>, BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(employee,int,age)> >
> employee_set;
```

Now, let us modify `employee` so that `employee::name` is actually a member of a nested `struct Bar`, and say `employee` contains two instances of `Bar`.

```
struct employee
{
  int           id;
  struct Bar
  {
    Bar(std::string name) : name(name) {}

    std::string name;
  } bar1, bar2;
  int           age;

  // ...
};
```

But you can't modify this declaration

```
ordered_non_unique<
      tag<name>,BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(employee,std::string,name)>
```

to indicate the nested `struct`'s data member directly. Instead, you need to modify the declaration to

```
ordered_non_unique<
  tag<name>,BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(employee,employee::Bar,bar1)>
```

We need a way to order the `employee::Bar` objects, so add a comparison operator to its definition

```
struct Bar
{
  // ...
  bool operator<(Bar const& other) const { return name < other.name; }
};
```

With these changes, if you index into the container using the tag `name`, you'll be ordering it based on the `bar1.name` data member.

Here's a [complete working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/509a88f34b0af9c6).

I also initialized `bar2.name` to contain the reverse sequence of characters as that contained in `bar1.name`, and added the option to index based on that using the tag `name2`.

Comment: thanks for the comment but I don't think it works. Think there are two Bar members in Foo, how can you differentiate the two Bar without quoting which Bar instance to check

Comment: @xiaodong I decided to play around with Boost.MultiIndex for the first time, and have posted a new example that I think is representative of the use case you've described. I also took the liberty to add the details from your comment to your question. Please make sure the description is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You can resort to [user-defined key extractors](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/key_extraction.html#user_defined_key_extractors):

```
struct Foobar1qux
{
  typedef int result_type;

  int operator()(const Foo &x)const{return x.bar1.qux;}
};

struct Foobar2qux
{
  typedef int result_type;

  int operator()(const Foo &x)const{return x.bar2.qux;}
};

typedef multi_index_container<
  Foo,
  indexed_by<
    ordered_non_unique<Foobar1qux>,
    ordered_non_unique<Foobar2qux>
  >
> multi_t1;
```

A more generic approach is to cascade key extractors as shown in [one of the examples](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/examples.html#example6) of Boost.MultiIndex documentation:

```
template<class KeyExtractor1,class KeyExtractor2>
struct key_from_key
{
public:
  typedef typename KeyExtractor1::result_type result_type;

  key_from_key(
    const KeyExtractor1& key1_=KeyExtractor1(),
    const KeyExtractor2& key2_=KeyExtractor2()):
    key1(key1_),key2(key2_)
  {}

  template<typename Arg>
  result_type operator()(Arg& arg)const
  {
    return key1(key2(arg));
  }

private:
  KeyExtractor1 key1;
  KeyExtractor2 key2;
};

typedef multi_index_container<
  Foo,
  indexed_by<
    ordered_non_unique<
      key_from_key<
        member<Foo::Bar,int,&Foo::Bar::qux>,
        member<Foo,Foo::Bar,&Foo::bar1>
      >
    >,
    ordered_non_unique<
      key_from_key<
        member<Foo::Bar,int,&Foo::Bar::qux>,
        member<Foo,Foo::Bar,&Foo::bar2>
      >
    >
  >
> multi_t2;
```